# Missing css in Django admin

Tags: python, django, static

I'm used nginx + unicorn + Django and absence css only in Django admin. I'm not understand the reason. Static is shown on all a pages besides admin. In terminal is see 200code: http://joxi.ru/KAxLRZEi4kdQYA In console missing error: http://joxi.ru/12M6KL0i4jpO9A
P.S. I make collectstatic.

settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'homepage',
'info',
'login',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect mime type resolve **nginx** settings. It sends css, but set default `Content-Type: text/plain`. Add `include mime.types;` (or set path to another *mime.types* file) for *nginx.conf* or set it [manualy](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types)